# How can I fix a Word template that doesn't let me insert image in-line?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have this Word template where inserted (pasted) images are behind the text as can see here:

This is how it's pasted inside Word.

[image: screenshot]

Any other Layout Option I choose wouldn't fix this and make it truly inline.

This is what the image really looks like:

[image: screenshot]

[Here is the sample document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ushh53t9f4uthu/Title.docx?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share a link to the problem file. Here's how: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258  Is your paste location inside a table cell with fixed height?

Comment: added. thanks for your edits

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, if I choose one of the setings in following red box, such as "Top and Button" for it and then choose "Behind Text", the image would be shown correctly.

[image]

[image]